# Transfer value from view to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I've been trying to pass and id of an user to my controller from a view. I've been using ActionLink in view and ActionResult in controller. Nothing seems to help. I've also tried Html.BeginForm but it didn't work as well. In both cases i get a Resource Not Found error in the end.

Here is my controller function:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult ApproveUser(int id)
{
    UserDTO user = new UserDTO();
    user = userService.GetUser(id);
    user.Approved = true;
    userService.Update(user);
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Here is my view (ActionLink):

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Users)
{
    if (item.Approved == false)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Login)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Approve",  "ApproveUser", "AdminController", new { id = item.Id }, null)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
}
```

This is the screenshot of the error:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/cvdSYg1.png]

Comment: You can have controllers in client and servers.  There are 5 steps that occur when you send a request 1) Client sends a request using a POST 2) Server receives request with GET 3) Server processes the request 4) Server sends a response with a POST 5) Client get the response with a GET.  You say it is a server error.  Not sure if the code posted is client or server.

Comment: Honestly a little bit confused what you're talking about since i'm a student, but i am not using any particular server, this is just a client with a sql database.

Comment: You have an ApproveUser HttpPost method in the controller. Do you have another one for the GET? Your ActionLink is a GET, not POST. If you haven't got another ApproveUser, it's normal get a 404 error

Comment: @jdweng Huh? Those 5 steps sounds completely made up. Why would a POST request somehow turn into a GET request on the server? I appreciate you're trying to help, but you're only making things more confusing.

Comment: You are using HTTP where there is a request that gets sent from client to server and then a response is returned from server to client.  It looks like your code is only doing steps 1 & 5.  Looks like your URL may be bad. The URL should look like "http://www.imgur.com/a/BVgxn7Y".

Comment: @Kruem please post your attempt using a form. Clicking an hyperlink would only result in a GET request, and thus would not reach a method that only accepts POST requests. A form is necessary to perform a POST request, unless you've implemented some JavaScript.

Comment: @mason : Because that is what actually happens with HTTP.  The client sends a request and the server receives the request.

Comment: @jdweng Right...but a client doesn't send a POST request and then somehow the server receives it as a GET request. Your first comment is entirely misleading. I know you're trying to help, but I think you're just confusing the situation. I suggest you remove your comments here and take care to post information that isn't misleading in the future.

Comment: @mason here is the attempt using form - https://imgur.com/a/zZ9ZiyB

Comment: @mason : GET/PUT is optional and is the body of the HTML message.   PUT add body at the send endpoint and GET removes body at receive endpoint.

Comment: @jdweng What? That makes no sense. I'm sorry, you're just mucking things up. Some verb is necessary as part of the HTTP protocol, not optional. And it would be in the header of the request, not the body. And you can have a GET request with a body, though not just from simply clicking on a hyperlink. Not sure why you're bringing PUT into this discussion either.

Comment: @Kruem Your code should be directly in the question. As code, not an image of code. And you need to decide whether you want to do this from a hyperlink (and thus it must be a GET request) or from a form submission, which is usually a POST request. Rahul's answer does a nice job of demonstrating how to do this with a hyperlink and GET request.

Comment: @mason what are you talking about? My code is directly in the question, as code. There is only one image and that's the screenshot of the error i was getting. I know i need to decide that's why i said i tried both ways and none of them used to work. Please read the question before answering.

Comment: I did read the question. You didn't put the form attempt in the question as code. You've put it in the comment as a link to an image.

Comment: I know it may feel like that's unnecessary and redundant, but we expect questions to be of use to future visitors to the site, not just the first person that asked the question. So hosting the actual code on some seperate resource like imgur runs a serious risk that the image will be removed or moved to a different URL, thus removing a vital part of the question. Then, we want code as text, not images, because text is easier to index, easier to copy/paste into answers, saves bandwidth, and some people have imgur blocked by corporate filters.

Comment: @mason i've posted the attempt using form using imgur. yes. I don't have the attempt using form written as code. I only have a screenshot of it saved. I'm not gonna write the whole code here when i have the screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to pass an id using `@Html.ActionLink`. You can do this in this way:

First specify the correct route, you have mentioned `AdminController` as `Controller` parameter. You only need to specify `Admin` there. Change your `id` to a more specific term like `itemid`. The `id` can confuse the route.

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Users)
{

    if (item.Approved == false)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Login)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Approve", "ApproveUser", "Admin", new { itemid = item.Id }, null)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
}
```

Remove the attributes from your `Controller` method since default verb is `HttpGet` and that is what you are doing here. There is no need for `ValidateAntiForgeryToken` attribute since you are not generating it firstly and it is used for `POST` requests during form submission.

```
public ActionResult ApproveUser(int itemid)
{
    UserDTO user = new UserDTO();
    user = userService.GetUser(itemid);
    user.Approved = true;
    userService.Update(user);
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```